# How to pass or convert data(which is stored in sqlite database) from sqlite database to xml?

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

How to pass or convert data(which is stored in sqlite database) from sqlite database to xml ?
so that from xml i can convert it again to sql 
Since i am using ASP.net on one end and android on other hand

How to maintain the common database between them?

Answer (score 0):

On the Android side, you could convert data from SQLITE into Objects and then write a marshaller to an XML using XStream. I'm sure there should be some other library you can download for ASP.net that works like XStream and would allow you to deserialize from XML into objects, and then back into the database.